# Is $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$ integral over $\mathbb{Q}[f,g]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

I have got this question on my Commutative Algebra midterm exam.

Consider the $\mathbb{Q}$-subalgebra $C$ of $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$ generated by two polynomials.

$f_1 = x^3+6x^2y+12xy^2+8y^3+2$

$f_2 = x^2+ 4xy+1$

Is $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$ integral over $C$?

I have two potentially working ways to find an answer.

First: $x,y$ are integral,iff $C[x]$ and $C[y]$ are finitely generated $C$-modules.

Second [Question from SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1528983/x-is-integral-over-r-if-and-only-if-for-every-minimal-prime-mathfrak-q-of).
Alas, I don't know what are the minimal prime ideals of 
$\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$

Let us notice that $f_1-2 = (x+2y)^3$ and $f_2-1 = (x+2y)^2 - y^2$.

Why does this mean that $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$ is integral over $С$?

Comment: The finitely generated module stuffs are transitive : if $A=\sum_j a_j B$ and $B=\sum_i b_i C$ then $A=\sum_{i,j} a_jb_iC$ is finitely generated $C$-module. So $f_1-2 = (x+2y)^3$ means $x+2y$ is integral over $Q[f_1]$ and $f_2-1 = (x+2y)^2 - y^2$ means $y$ is integral over $Q[x+2y,f_2]$ thus over $Q[f_1,f_2]$ and $x$ is integral over $Q[f_1,f_2,y]$ thus over $Q[f_1,f_2]$. I would like to see the answer for the integral closure of $Q[g_1,g_2]$ for arbitrary algebraically independent polynomials in $Q[x,y]$.